# IOS Renaming Symbols for avoiding duplicate?

Tags: ios

I read in SO that Renaming symbols was an effective way for removing duplicate symbol errors. If i wanted to rename jsonkit and afnetworking how do i go about doing so?

Comment: Can you provide us with examples of duplicates that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Are you sure you want to give up any chance of upgrading one or the other?  If you get duplicate symbol errors then just remove one of the libraries.  Those libraries are both open source so furthermore you can edit them by hand to remove the conflicting classes.

Comment: Well yes i am pretty sure i won't require upgrading. The reason why i am opting for such a solution is that My end target will be a framework file with neither JSON or AFNetworking header files as public

Comment: Do you mean refactoring? You can right click a symbol in Xcode and select Refactor>Rename.

Comment: The problem is searching for all symbols. I was hoping there would be proper way to do that

Comment: Maybe off topic, but a better way might be to use Cocoapods. I dont think that refactoring libraries will make you a happy camper.